# simple apache redirect question

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

I would like to set up a simple apache redirect that redirects URL A to URL B

A: `http://myURL.example/msc3/fr`

B: `http://myURL.example/msc3/fr/index_fr`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  http://myURL.example/msc3/fr  http://myURL.example/msc3/fr/index_fr
```

I think I am close but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only specify the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) in [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), in case of the .htaccess file only the URL path without the contextual path prefix (in this case `/`). So:

```
RewriteRule  ^msc3/fr  http://example.com/msc3/fr/index_fr
```

Note that this will match any URL that’s path just *begins* with `/msc3/fr` as `^` marks the start of the string.